# CREATE TABLE Issue on Intermediate Table

Tags: mysql

having an issue getting this to work. MySQL keeps throwing the following:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES order' at line 6
```

And the SQL is:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user_orders`;
CREATE TABLE `user_orders` (
`user_orders_user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
`user_orders_order_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`user_orders_user_id`, `user_orders_order_id`),
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id),
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES order(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

`user_orders` acts as an intermediate table for `User.id` and `Order.id` (i.e. holds a record for each order made by a user). I feel like I'm missing something obvious. The User table has no FK's and the Order table has an FK (`user_id`) to `User.id` (with `ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE`).

Hopefully I'm just tired and it's a minor syntax issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a comma that should not be there on this line:

```
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id),
```

Besides, in your table you have not field such as `user_id` and `order_id`. Infact you have `user_orders_user_id` and `user_orders_order_id`

Besides, you have to include the `order` between the `'` because is a reserved word as suggested by ypercube.

Comment: Still no dice, after that fix (I think I just fat fingered it when copy + pasting):

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB' at line 7`

Comment: Thanks. Still having issues - I think it's getting hung up on my ON DELETE/ON UPDATE cascades?

`FOREIGN KEY (user_orders_user_id) REFERENCES user(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_orders_order_id) REFERENCES order(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;`

(same error as prior)

Answer (score 2):

Do not use names for fields and tables that are reserved keywords, like `order`. Escape it with `` `order` ``   if you have to:

```
FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES `order`(id)
```

Comment: @elithar: I think AurelioDeRosa deserves the correct answer, as he had already found 2 issues with your query, before I answered.